# Equation with arctan

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to prove

$$\arctan(x+1)-\arctan x = \arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}\right)$$

for every $x$.

I was thinking $f(x)=\arctan(x+1)-\arctan x -\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}\right)$.

If $Df(x)=0$ for every $x$, then the function is constant and I can also see that $f(0)=0$.

But it seems quite difficult to differentiate $f(x)$ and prove $Df(x)=0$ for every $x$, is there any other way?

Comment: Replace "derive" by "differentiate" in your text, derive means not differentiate, if that is what you mean.

Comment: 1. Why do you think it's hard to take the derivative? 2. An alternative method is to take the tangent.

Comment: I was was thinking all three derivates needed a common numerator Andrei

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relation you want to prove is equivalent to the simpler form
$$
\underbrace{\arctan (x+1) - \arctan x-\frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan(x^2+x+1)}_{f(x)}=0
$$

This way you can check that
$$
f'(x)= \dfrac{1}{1+(x+1)^2}-\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}+\dfrac{2x+1}{1+(x^2+x+1)^2} = 0
$$

which, together with the fact that $f(0)=0$, establishes the result.

---

Note:
$$
\arctan(1/u) = \frac{\pi}{2} -\arctan u, \quad u> 0
$$

$$
\arctan(1/u) = -\frac{\pi}{2} -\arctan u, \quad u < 0
$$